# How to execute dependent, sequential calls and return an array with all responses?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have a redux-observable epic which polls an API and I'm trying to execute three dependent, sequential http requests and gather all responses in an array.

toArray() is never executed in this case because concatMap() is not finished. I tried to move the calls inside of a mergeMap() and gather the array there, but only the last call was in the array.

```
timer(0, POLLING_INTERVAL).pipe(
        concatMap(() => from(fetchApi(url1))),
        concatMap(response => {
          const url2 = 'URL based on first response';

          return from(fetchApi(url2));
        }),
        concatMap(response => {
          const url3 = 'URL based on second response';

          return from(fetchApi(url3));
        }),
        toArray(), // expected [{response1}, {response2}, {response3}]
        map(data => ({
          type: ActionTypes.FETCH_SUCCESS,
          payload: { data },
        })),
        catchError(error =>
          of({
            type: ActionTypes.FETCH_FAILED,
            payload: { error },
          }),
        ),
        takeUntil(
          action$.pipe(
            ofType(ActionTypes.CANCEL_POLLING),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Each operator takes in an Observable stream and creates an output stream with its output. So the second concatMap takes in the response from the fetchApi(url1) and outputs the fetchApi(url2). At that point, the data fetched from fetchApi(url1) is no longer accessible in the stream. So even if the stream completed and `toArray` could complete, it could not access the prior two `concatMap` outputs as it is written. See martin's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do. `toArray()` won't help you because `timer` never completes and `toArray()` emits only when its source completes.

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
timer(0, POLLING_INTERVAL).pipe(
  concatMap(() => from(fetchApi(url1)).pipe(
    concatMap(response1 => {
      const url2 = 'URL based on first response';
      return forkJoin([of(response1), fetchApi(url2)]);
    }),
    concatMap(([response1, response2]) => {
      const url3 = 'URL based on second response';
      return forkJoin([of(response1), of(response2), fetchApi(url3)]);
    }),
  )),
  map(data => ({
    type: ActionTypes.FETCH_SUCCESS,
    payload: { data },
  })),
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution works perfectly, but is this the cleanest and "most reactive" way to do this?

Comment: Btw. I use toArray() inside of the timer for parallel calls
timer(0, POLLING_INTERVAL).pipe(
        switchMap(() =>
          from(requestsOptions).pipe(
            mergeMap(options => from(fetchApi(apiName, path, options))),
            toArray(),
          ),
        ),

Comment: Since you need to make multiple subsequent calls and you have to pass along all response I don't think there's any better solution.